# hebrew in word for mac 2011

Tags: microsoft-office

does anyone knows how to fix the hebrew problem in microsoft office 2011 for mac (WORD)?
when I load a document that have been edited by word in windows the problem is solved, so I guessed it was something about the file configuration.
any suggestions?

Shahar.

Comment: What are you talking about? Please be more specific.

Comment: What *is* the problem in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are talking about the lack of right-to-left language support in Mac Office. As far as I know there is NO fix and it is simply not supported for new documents, but opening a document created in Word 2010 or other PC versions with RtL support will allow you to edit.